# Azure log analytics: monitoring successful sign-ins following repeated sign-in failures

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'd like to use Azure Log Analytics to create a monitoring alert for possible brute-force attempts on my users' accounts. That is to say, I'd like to be notified by Azure (or, at the very least, be able to manually run the script to obtain the data) when a user's account is successfully authenticated into O365 following a number of failed attempts.

I know how to parse the logs to, for example, obtain the number of unsuccessful sign-in attempts by all users during a defined period (see the example below):

```
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated between(datetime("2018-11-19 00:00:00") .. datetime("2018-11-19 23:59:59")) 
| where ResultType == "50074"
| summarize FailedSigninCount = count() by UserDisplayName 
| sort by FailedSigninCount desc
```

But I don't know how to script the following:

- A user has created 9 unsuccessful sign-in attempts (type 50074) and
  created a successful sign-in attempt.
- Within a 60-second period.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you considered using Azure Security Center? It will do a lot of this for you.

Comment: I have, yes, but my employer doesn't have a license for it

Comment: In the SinginLogs, does the failed/success login message contains user info(or do you have a way to associate the correct user to the message)? and what do you mean about within a 60s period?

Comment: @IvanYang - yes, the failed/success message contains user info (i.e. name) and I can query using UserPrimaryName (i.e. identity). The reference to 60 seconds is an arbitrary amount of time between the number of the defined number of failed attempts, followed by the successful attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Azure Sentinel community GitHub and see if the queries there help. Specifically I added https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/blob/master/Detections/SigninLogs/SigninBruteForce-AzurePortal.txt which I think more or less does what you are after - also repasted below. Hope that helps.

```
// Evidence of Azure Portal brute force attack in SigninLogs:
// This query returns results if there are more than 5 authentication failures and a successful authentication 
// within a 20-minute window.
let failureCountThreshold = 5;
let successCountThreshold = 1;
let timeRange = ago(1d);
let authenticationWindow = 20m;
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= timeRange 
| extend OS = DeviceDetail.operatingSystem, Browser = DeviceDetail.browser
| extend StatusCode = tostring(Status.errorCode), StatusDetails = tostring(Status.additionalDetails)
| extend State = tostring(LocationDetails.state), City = tostring(LocationDetails.city)
| where AppDisplayName contains "Azure Portal"
// Split out failure versus non-failure types
| extend FailureOrSuccess = iff(ResultType in ("0", "50125", "50140"), "Success", "Failure")
| summarize StartTimeUtc = min(TimeGenerated), EndTimeUtc = max(TimeGenerated), 
makeset(IPAddress), makeset(OS), makeset(Browser), makeset(City), makeset(ResultType),
FailureCount=countif(FailureOrSuccess=="Failure"),
SuccessCount = countif(FailureOrSuccess=="Success") 
by bin(TimeGenerated, authenticationWindow), UserDisplayName, UserPrincipalName, AppDisplayName
| where FailureCount>=failureCountThreshold and SuccessCount>=successCountThreshold
```